# Can i know what is the error in these lines of code

Tags: html, ajax, spring

```
Code:
var formdate:{name:$("#name").val(), date:$("date").value
}
$.ajax({
          type : "POST",
          contentType : "application/json", 
          url : "localhost:8080/company/addrelease",
          data : JSON.stringify(formdata),
          dataType : 'json',
          success : function(result) {
            if(result.status == "Done"){
              console.log("value added");
            }else{          
            console.log("not done");
            }
          },
          error : function(e) {
                console.log("error");
}
        });
```

**Question**

This is the line of code in which i'm trying to call my rest Api with ajax api call.
But it goes till the ajax statement but soon after that it gets refreshed and stops working and again.  Any suggestions to get through this would be appreciated.

Comment: var formdate = {name: $("#name").val(), date: $("date").val()}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> soon after that it gets refreshed

My guess is that you've placed this code inside form submit handler:

```
function onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // your code
}


<form onsubmit={onSubmit}>
    ...
    <button type="submit" />
</form>
```

If you don't call `e.preventDefault()` the form will try to submit itself, making a http request to url specified in the form. If no url attribute is specified, it will submit to the current url e.g. the page will refresh. Http request called by you (ajax) is async action, and you don't see it working because default submit action happens before that.